# Simple gas/fluid dynamics source code

Tags: c++, physics, voxel

I have a 3D matrix of voxel objects that I'd like to use to store the state of some basic physics principles in. The intention here is to then represent the volume in real-time (~30FPS) in a video game.
I would like to try to have the volume capable of the following:
1. Store fluid and gas types of various weights and follow basic interaction principles. For example oxygen is lighter than water.
2. Be able to determine pressure.
3. Be able to interact with 'solid' objects. So a hollow 3D box can store something that won't 'leak' out.

All of this can be very basic and can forgo any 'accuracy' tests.

Happy to accept ideas as well as any decent resources for further reading. I would however posit that I don't believe I have the skill to take a paper or advanced equation and roll my own library.

Answer (score 4):

Well, multifluids simulation is not exactly easy. What you could do is use SPH (Smoothed particle hydrodynamics) as this method allows for relatively simple simulation of complex interfaces. If I'm correct it is also widely used in the gaming/animation industry, e.g. Blender uses it for its fluid simulation. I suggest you try to do a single fluid simulation first before you look into more complex things. Be prepared that this will take quite some effort and depending on what type of accuracy/resolution you are looking for parallelization will be required. If you have more question on the topic of SPH specifically I'll try and answer them.

Comment: Thanks some keywords in there (SPH) have yielded some new resources for me. However I sticking point with SPH is that it appears fairly difficult to render the particles or 'metaballs' in 3D polygons. At least with Voxels there are well documented and implemented algorithms to do this (Marching Cubes), and I have a running implementation of this already. I will keep looking however.

Comment: I don't know anything about that as I'm using SPH for engineering purposes, but I see your point.

Comment: @S.Richmond Actually metaballs and voxel grid isosurface generation algorithms are more or less the same.  Both rely on you providing a field density to give a location for a boundary (your polygonal face) - Marching Cubes is just one example.

Comment: Do you have much experience working with meta all ISO extraction? Any resources would be great.

Comment: I do, but only in one very narrow field: fluidics rendering in Pixar's RenderMan, so unfortunately I can't give you any general help.  There are many resources out there on the web, but you need to know the terminology, and they're almost exclusively hardcore computer science papers - very unfriendly things.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach in 3D graphics I have seen are modelled on voxel-based implementations of the [Navier-Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equations.  Searching for this should give many papers on approaches to implementing this method in code or even ready made libraries, but as Azrael3000 stated, computational fluidics is as difficult as it sounds - and *very* math heavy.  Thankfully it can also be split into many threads easily, so the best way to get to your 30FPS is push the calculations onto the GPU.

Another thing to remember is 'voxels' and 'frames' are graphics terms.  The approach to the equations (which are continuous functions remember) is called **FDTD** - *Finite Difference Time Domain*.  Which in English means sample the field as discrete points in time and space.

Comment: I second that. GPU is definitely the way to go on parallelization.

Comment: Do you have any resources handy? I've been googling for a bit now and have come up with little to nothing about implementations using Voxels.

Comment: Going straight for a GPU solution: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html.  Also see my edit.